# How to represent dynamic JSON keys in Scala when using circe

Tags: scala, circe

I'm trying to represent the following JSON as a Scala case class:

```
     {
       "cars": {
          "THIS IS A DYNAMIC KEY 1": {
            "name": "bla 1",
          },
          "THIS IS A DYNAMIC KEY 2": {
            "name": "bla 2",
          }
          ...
      }
```

However, my JSON has dynamic keys that I won't know at runtime, and I'd like to use circe to encode/decode. I'm using the correct way to represent this using Scala?

```
import io.circe.generic.JsonCodec

@JsonCodec
case class Cars(cars: List[Car])

@JsonCodec
case class Car(whatShouldThisBe: CarDetails) // Not sure how to represent this?

@JsonCodec
case class CarDetails(name: String)
```

Comment: How "dynamic" is the key? One from a set/finite list of possibilities or "any valid string"? If the former, you can use `sealed trait` and several implemenations. If the latter, model `Car` as a tuple or `Cars` as a whole as a `Map`.

Comment: Thanks, the key can be any valid string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can just use a `Map[String, CarDetails]`. Your ADT then becomes:

```
import io.circe.generic.JsonCodec

@JsonCodec
case class Cars(cars: Map[String, CarDetails])

@JsonCodec
case class CarDetails(name: String)
```

The only tricky bit might be if you require there to be at least one CarDetails object, or if zero is acceptable. Circe does appear to support `cats.data.NonEmptyMap` should that be required.

Comment: Upvoted, this is the best solution if there's no particular reason to need the `Car` case class level.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to handle a case like this would probably be to change the `cars` member of the `Cars` case class to have a type like `Map[String, CarDetails]`, dropping the `Car` case class altogether. If you do that, your code will work exactly as-is (minus the `Car` definition), and will decode the JSON example you've provided.

If you want something closer to your case class structure, you could do the following:

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.generic.JsonCodec

case class Cars(cars: List[Car])

object Cars {
  implicit val decodeCars: Decoder[Cars] =
    Decoder[Map[String, CarDetails]].prepare(_.downField("cars")).map(kvs =>
      Cars(
        kvs.map {
          case (k, v) => Car(k, v)
        }.toList
      )
    )
}

// I've added an `id` member here as a way to hold on to the JSON key.
case class Car(id: String, whatShouldThisBe: CarDetails)

@JsonCodec
case class CarDetails(name: String)
```

This will decode the same JSON but will include the dynamic keys in the `Car` level.